# Property of nilpotent elements in a ring with prime char

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a ring with prime characteristic $p$ and suppose $a\in R$ such that $a^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$, then does $k \mid p$?

I don't know whether this fact is true or not. Can anyone share a proof of it, if this fact is true (BTW my first post on this site, nice to meet y'all :) )

Comment: If $a^k = 0$, what can you say about $a^{k+1}$?  I think you can see what this implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $R$ be the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in ${\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}$. It has characteristic $3$. However, $a = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\0 & 0}$ satifies $a^2 = 0$.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that R is a commutative ring. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have any nonzero element such that $x^k=0$ for some $k> 0$, then you can make $k$ arbitrarily high... how would you expect it to divide any fixed number?  Well, let's suppose you meant minimal $k$.

Let $F_3$ be the field of three elements and consider $F_3[x]/(x^2)$.   Then $x^2=0$ in this ring (slightly abusing notation) but $2$ does not divide the characteristic, $3$.

Comment: yah I meant minimal k. Thanks :)